# Updating to Ruby 2.0 broke my asset pipeline

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, asset-pipeline, ruby-2.0

I installed Ruby 2.0 to try it out with my Rails 3.1.12 app.

All of the same gems are able to be installed with Ruby 2.0.0. `Gemfile.lock` doesn't even change.

But now when I load pages, I get javascript errors that `jQuery` isn't defined. And none of the files that my manifest says to include show up, in development. I tried pushing to a staging env, to see if they'd be included during precompile, but they weren't.

Here's [production, still with Ruby 1.9.2](http://problemchildmag.com/submit), here's [staging with Ruby 2.0.0](http://pcmag-staging.herokuapp.com/submit), and here's [the full diff of what I changed between the two](https://github.com/chadoh/pcmag/pull/4/files).

wtf?

Comment: I didn't think rails 3.1.12 had been updated updated to work with ruby 2.0.

Comment: Please use rails 3.2.13 or rails 4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rails 3.1.x **does not work** with Ruby >= 2.0.

If you want to use the wonderfully speedy Ruby >= 2.0, **upgrade to Rails >= 3.2.13**. (It will be worth the effort.)

Comment: This is helpful, I'm having the same problem. Do you have a source for this, though? Thanks.